# What model to fit to call center data

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, forecasting

I have a dataset with calls from day 1 to day 340. What model can I fit to mathematically capture the pattern?

There are only 1 or 2 digit number of calls on all days except day 61.62.63 and 121.122.123 and 170 days when there are 3-4 digit number of calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are going to be able to capture this pattern unless you include some kind of information around those 3 blow up periods. Were these holidays, new product release, stimulus checks, govt requirements, etc? Best make a variable to capture that. If you don't know why you had a sudden increase of 2 to 3 magnitudes, you should probably understand your data better.

Depending on your needs, a solid line graph with some well placed text and color might get you just as far as a fancy model. Eg, 98% of days we had roughly X calls, but during Holidays, calls increase Y%. Please consider temp hiring during holidays to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

What patterns do you want to capture? High and low activity hours? Operators' efficiency in solving issues?

In all cases, you can apply time-series algorithms like LSTM to predict values.

https://www.kaggle.com/code/amirrezaeian/time-series-data-analysis-using-lstm-tutorial

https://pub.towardsai.net/google-stock-predictions-using-an-lstm-neural-network-dbe785949a96

But, it might be interesting to use data viz together with machine learning to have many interesting views + easy filtering of any feature.

https://demos.qlik.com/qliksense/HelpdeskManagement?function=IT

https://data-science-at-swast-handover-poc-handover-yfa2kz.streamlitapp.com/

Comment: Does it answer your question? If not, please let me know.